# Find unix tree directory without the list of files

Tags: linux

I am looking to see the tree structure of a main directory on unix but without the files. "Tree" directory provides me the directory + files. How can i do directory only?

Comment: just use "tree -d" command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is bash script that recursively enters every directory starting from the current and prints its name:

```
#!/bin/bash

function loop {
    echo "$pad"${PWD##*/}
    for i in *
    do 
        if [ -d "$i" ] && [ -x "$i" ]
        then
            cd "$i"
            pad="$pad"$'\t'
            loop
        fi
    done
    pad=${pad#$'\t'}
    cd ..
}

loop
```

Test dir structure (using @User123's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48463023/4162356):

```
$ find . -type d
.
./test
./foo
./foo/456
./foo/123
```

and scripts output:

```
$ bash ../test.sh
test
        foo
                123
                456
        test
```

Comment: thanks for all the answers of everybody

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this simple `find` command to see directories under main directory:

`find . -type d`